# How can logrotate execution result in "service: not found"?

Tags: linux, debian, cron, logrotate

I am trying to understand the output of my logrotate script execution:

```
error: error running shared postrotate script for '/var/log/nginx/*.log '
logrotate_script: 2: logrotate_script: service: not found
error: error running non-shared postrotate script for /var/log/syslog of '/var/log/syslog '
logrotate_script: 2: logrotate_script: service: not found
error: error running shared postrotate script for '/var/log/mail.info
/var/log/mail.warn
/var/log/mail.err
/var/log/mail.log
/var/log/daemon.log
/var/log/kern.log
/var/log/auth.log
/var/log/user.log
/var/log/lpr.log
/var/log/cron.log
/var/log/debug
/var/log/messages '
```

As far as I understand, logrotate encounters an error while running the postrotate scripts for `nginx` and `syslog`, respectively `service nginx rotate >/dev/null` and `service rsyslog rotate > /dev/null`.

#### Logrotate script (`/etc/logrotate.d/nginx`)

```
/var/log/nginx/*.log {
    daily
    missingok
    rotate 365
    compress
    delaycompress
    notifempty
    create 0640 www-data www-data
    olddir /var/log/archives/nginx
    sharedscripts
    prerotate
            if [ -d /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate ]; then \
                    run-parts /etc/logrotate.d/httpd-prerotate; \
            fi \
    endscript
    postrotate
            invoke-rc.d nginx rotate >/dev/null 2>&1
    endscript
}
```

Logrotate is run through cron as root, and running the postrotate scripts manually goes without problems:

#### Crontab entry (root)

`00 00 * * * /usr/sbin/logrotate -s /var/lib/logrotate/status /etc/logrotate.conf`

#### Manual postrotate script execution

```
$ invoke-rc.d nginx rotate >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo $? 
0
```

What could explain this **`service:`**`not found` message ?

Comment: You are missing the path?! Try /usr/sbin/service

Answer (score 0):

Can you write the context of /etc/logrotate.conf or file with the ngix log rotation rules?

In rh/centos 'service' is in /sbin/service but in debian/ubuntu is in '/usr/sbin/service. Do you have absolute path in pre or post rotate?

Comment: I added the log rotation rules, which are the package's default.
As you can see, there is no absolute path.